# Read content of Registry.pol

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file

I'm trying to read content of the following file

```
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Registry.pol
```

in a C# application.

**Here is the snippet of code:**

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Registry.pol");
```

Despite this folder, this file exists and I run program from Administrator I always get exception of the following type System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException.

Could you please suggest solution to read the content?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure each folder has read right for Administrator?

Comment: Seems that you were right. I tried to read it in Windows Service and failed with an exception. When I tried to read for simple console everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

In the struggle to make windows a 64bit operating system and still have 32bit programs work, many 'special' solutions were applied. One is folder redirection. You are probably running a 32bit program on a 64bit machine. In that case, you will need to change your path from C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Registry.pol to C:\Windows\sysnative\GroupPolicy\User\Registry.pol. Here's a write up that explains the awesomeness of this portion of windows.

Comment: I don't see a write-up.